# React split data into bootstrap rows

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Sorry for this question, but it is my first every app with React and I am trying to style it nicely with Bootstrap.
Basically I want to display 9 elements in 3 rows containing 3 elements each. This is my code which works but is there a better way to do this?

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
            {recipes.slice(0, 3).map((recipe) => (
                <Recipe
                    ...
                />
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
            {recipes.slice(3, 6).map((recipe) => (
                <Recipe
                    ...
                />
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
            {recipes.slice(6, 9).map((recipe) => (
                <Recipe
                    ...
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them *all* in a single `row` by using `col-4` on the Recipe component...

```
class Recipe extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
    <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
        Recipe 
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/sMeYQQHDBN

Comment: The thing is that I've tried this, but when setting it to col-4 then it has a width of 1/3 parent container. I want it to have fixed width and it kept setting the width to 1/3 of parent.

Comment: Why are you using `row`? It's only meant to be used along with `col-*`. Can you provide more details on `Recipe`?

Comment: Recipe is a standard bootstrap card without additional styling. I'll try to describe this problem better - if recipe has class `col-4` then in fact there are 3 recipes per row as desired but they cover entire website width. I want my recipe to have fixed `width: 260px;`. If I apply `col-4` and styling `width: 260px;` then the `width` just doesn't work and cards are automatically stretched to cover entire width. That is why I don't use `col-`. It just stretches content to cover entire `width`.

Comment: Wow, I have just came up with something. Is it proper to set like the `parent` to be `col-6`, so it will take half of the screen and then for each child set `col-4` so each child will take `1/3 of 1/2` of the screen?